# Background Bibliography before self study Cohomology of Groups

Tags: algebraic-topology, group-cohomology

I'm interested in having a bibliography in order to be able to read the textbook "Cohomology of Groups" written by Keneth Brown with less dificulty. I think that I have no enough background in Algebraic Topology. What should I read before go with Brown's book?

Comment: This depends *heavily* on your background knowledge. "Not enough" is subjective, can you add a bit more details to your question? Perhaps an example of a statement that you do not follow, and the precise parts coming from AT that you find confusing?

Comment: Why not check the bibliography in Kenneth Brown's book? Or read the introduction and perhaps it is mentioned what is taken for granted in the book.

Comment: Well, I'm just have a course based on the textbook of James Munkres "Topology".